# Data type conversion issues

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, type-conversion

i'm currently trying to save some data in external memory via bluetooth LE. in order to send data i will first convert the string into HEX(ASCII) format

```
outbuffer += [UInt8](password.utf8)

String -> (HEX)ASCII
```

but when i retrieve the data back from external memory to get back the original data and i'm doing this

```
incomingData.getBytes(&array, length: 5)
let originalPassword = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(array).memory

(HEX)ASCII -> String
```

but i couldn't get back the original data. Can someone suggest me why? i'm new to this data conversion. Thank you

Comment: Is this the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String(array.map(UnicodeScalar.init).map(Character.init))
```